# Closed slice of affine space has closed projection

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let K be an algebraically closed field and suppose a set $\{ \overline{x} \} \times A$ is closed in the Zariski topology of the affine space $K^m \times K^n$ ($\overline{x} \in K^m, A\subset K^n$). Why is A necessarily closed in the Zariski topology of $K^n$? This seems stupidly easy, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You have a morphism $f\colon K^n \to K^m \times K^n$ defined by $f(y) = (\bar x,y)$, right? That's continuous, so...